# Combobox SelectedItem binding is Null in WPF using MVVM Pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am developing an application using WPF and MVVM pattern. I want to bind selectedItem from a combobox to my viewmodel, but it always Null. I have the following code:
This is a property I use for binding:

```
public Api.Project SelectedProject { get; set; }
```

This is the XAML code:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="textBox3" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Projects}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProject , Mode=TwoWay}"
          >
</ComboBox>
```

And when i use it here in the viewmodel it always gets null value:

```
public NewTaskViewModel()
    {
        ButtonClick = new ButtonCommandBinding(SendTask);
        ButtonClick.IsEnabled = true;
        Projects = new CollectionView(this.GetProjects());
        Projects.CurrentChanged += new EventHandler(projects_CurrentChanged);
    }

    void projects_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Tasks = new CollectionView(this.GetTaskLists());
        Users = new CollectionView(this.GetProjectAssignedUsers());
    }

    public IEnumerable<Api.TaskList> GetTaskLists()
    {
        var tasksLists = connection.GetTaskLists(this.SelectedProject.Id);
        return tasksLists;
    }
```

The SelectedProject is always null I am not sure what i am doing wrong, I hope for a little help. Cheers.

Comment: Can you post more code which will replicate your issue.

Comment: I have just edited the post and i added some code.

Comment: Have you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Yes I implemented INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: So public Api.Project SelectedProject { get; set; } ? where is NotifyPropertyChange here?